# Octaves don't sound like the same notes

Tags: octave

I keep reading how two notes an octave apart sound like the same notes. I understand that theres a doubling of the frequency,  so theres no real beats. But one sounds like a significantly higher tone, that's all. I can't transcribe something and substitute a C5 for C4 and think, ok that's the right note, just an octave off.
Is there something I'm not listening for ?

Comment: Are you saying that an octave doesn't sound the same? If yes, you may be out of tune, or I just may be reading the question wrong.

Comment: when you harmonize songs (ie play chords), then you'll notice that you can substitute any note for its octave and it'll sound just as good. that's what inversions basically do.

Comment: Is your question really about transcription and trying to get the right octave by ear? If you are transcribing a melody that started on C5, but you started on C4 and got all the *relative* intervals of the melody correct, I would say the mistaken octave is a minor issue. On the other hand, if the melody moved by major third and you transcribed a major 10th that would be an important mistake involving the octave.

Answer (score 0):

They're 'the same but different'.  The same pitch class but different pitches.  Maybe not too easy to explain the 'sameness' in words, but I hope you can HEAR it, and you're just complaining about not quite understanding a description!